# Get the count and percentage by grouping values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following Dataframe in pandas,

```
Score   Risk
30      High Risk
50      Medium Risk
70      Medium Risk
40      Medium Risk
80      Low Risk
35      High Risk
65      Medium Risk
90      Low Risk
```

I want get total count, group by count and percentage the Risk column by its values, like this:

```
Expected output
Risk Category   Count   Percentage
High Risk       2       25.00
Medium Risk     4       50.00
Low Risk        2       25.00
Total           8       100.00
```

Can someone explain how can I achieve the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with count percentages, join in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), add `total` row and last if necessary convert index to column:

```
s = df.groupby('Risk')['Score'].size()
df = pd.concat([s, s / s.sum() * 100], axis=1, keys=('count','Percentage'))
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum().astype(int)
print (df)
             count  Percentage
Risk                          
High Risk        2        25.0
Low Risk         2        25.0
Medium Risk      4        50.0
Total            8       100.0


df = df.rename_axis('Risk Category').reset_index()
print (df)
  Risk Category  count  Percentage
0     High Risk      2        25.0
1      Low Risk      2        25.0
2   Medium Risk      4        50.0
3         Total      8       100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get a fairly clean answer using `pivot_table` since this can automatically create the margin totals for you.

```py
summary = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index='Risk', aggfunc='count', margins='row', margins_name='Total'
    )
    .assign(Percentage=lambda df: df['Score'] / df.loc['Total', 'Score'] * 100)
    .rename_axis('Risk Category')
    .reset_index()
)

print(summary)
  Risk Category  Score  Percentage
0     High Risk      2        25.0
1      Low Risk      2        25.0
2   Medium Risk      4        50.0
3         Total      8       100.0
```